# Scraping hidden product details on a webpage using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Sorry I am a Selenium noob and have done a lot of reading but am still having trouble getting the product price (£0.55) from this page:
https://groceries.asda.com/product/spaghetti-tagliatelle/asda-spaghetti/36628. Product details are not visible when parsing the html using bs4. Using Selenium I can get a string of the entire page and can see the price in there (using the following code). I should be able to extract the price from this somehow but would prefer a less hacky solution.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Paul\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://groceries.asda.com/product/tinned-tomatoes/asda-smart-price-chopped-tomatoes-in-tomato-juice/19560')
content = browser.page_source
```

If I run something like this:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("bodyContainerTemplate")
print(elem)
```

It just returns: selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="df23fae6-e99c-403c-a992-a1adf1cb8010", element="6d9aac0b-2e98-4bb5-b8af-fcbe443af906")

The price is the text associated with this element: p class="prod-price"  but I cannot seem to get this working. How should I go about getting this text (the product price)?

Comment: The reason some of the info from the page is missing is that part of webpage is rendered in Javascript. check out [this](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) for less "hacky" solution

Comment: You can get product data from an API. `https://groceries.asda.com/api/items/view?itemid=36628&responsegroup=extended&cacheable=true&storeid=4565&shipdate=currentDate&requestorigin=gi`, no need to use Selenium. `python-requests` all the way!

Comment: try `print(elem.text)` instead

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. An API sure makes it easier!

Answer (score 3):

The type of `elem` is `WebElement`. If you need to extract text value of web-element you might use below code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("prod-price-inner")
print(elem.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution, it works with selenium and beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url='https://groceries.asda.com/product/spaghetti-tagliatelle/asda-spaghetti/36628'

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)

data = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

ele = soup.find('span',{'class':'prod-price-inner'})

print ele.text

driver.quit()
```

It will print :

```
£0.55
```